# Can try-catch not handle an error in solidity?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have an internal function

```
function _somefunction() internal {
    if (address(attr) != address(0)) {
        try attr.maybedoesntexist() {
        } catch Error(string memory message) {
            emit SomethingFailed();
        } catch {
            emit SomethingFailed();
        }
    }
}
```

When I test this in hardhat I set `attr` to be a non-contract, but somehow the error `function call to a non-contract account` goes through the first catch and the whole thing reverts.

No other function uses `attr` and the error is completely dependent on whether `attr` is a contract account. Can catch actually not handle some errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions from calls to non-contracts are currently (v0.8) not caught by `try/catch`.

You can validate whether the address is a contract, and only invoke calls on contracts:

```
// length of attr's bytecode is 0, it's not a contract
if (address(attr).code.length == 0) {
    return;
}

try attr.maybedoesntexist() {
```